# Determine if the matrix is idempotent?

Tags: matrices, inverse, idempotents

I am dealing with an example to show that the matrix($M = I − X(X'X)^{−1}X'$) is idempotent. X is a matrix with T rows and k columns and I the unit matrix of dimension T. And then to determine the rank of this matrix by using the properties of the trace of the matrix.
1.
Idempotent means that matrix $A^2=A*A=A$

$$M = I − X(X'X)^{−1}X'$$
$$M = XX' − X(X'X)^{−1}X'$$
$$MM = (XX' − X(X'X)^{−1}X')(XX' − X(X'X)^{−1}X')$$
$$MM = (XX' − X(X'X)^{−1}X')(I − I)$$
-> MM is not idempotent

Is that correct?

2.
$$Tr(AB)=Tr(BA)$$
$$Tr(M)=Tr(I − X(X'X)^{−1}X') = Tr(I − I) = Tr(0) = 0$$

Are my assumptions correct?

**UPDATE**

$$Tr(A-B)=Tr(A) - Tr(B)$$
$$Tr(M)=Tr(I) − Tr(X(X'X)^{−1}X')) = Tr(I) − Tr(I) = Tr(0)  or Tr(I)= Rank(n)$$
Is this correct?

Comment: Why would $XX' = I$? That may not be true.

Comment: I am struggeling to find rules to determine the solution of the above example? Do you have a link or sth?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. You've wrongly assumed that $XX'=I$. To prove that $M$ is idempotent, note that $Y^2=(X(X'X)^{−1}X')^2=X\underbrace{(X'X)^{−1}X'X}_{=I}(X'X)^{−1}X'=:Y$, so $M^2=(I-Y)^2=I-2Y+Y^2=I-Y=M$.
2. Indeed $\operatorname{tr}(X(X'X)^{−1}X')=\operatorname{tr}(X'X(X'X)^{−1})=\operatorname{tr}(I)$, but the size of this $I$ is $k\times k$, while the $I$ in $\operatorname{tr}(I-X(X'X)^{−1}X')$ has size $T\times T$. So, no, the trace of $M$ is **not** zero in general, but $\operatorname{tr}(I_T)-\operatorname{tr}(I_k)=T-k$. To find the rank of $M$ using the trace, observe that (a) every eigenvalue of $M$ is either $0$ or $1$ (why?) and (b) $M$ is unitarily diagonalizable (again, why?). So, the rank is equal to the trace. (Why~y~y~~???)

Comment: For 1. Would you be so kind to provide me a hint, to get to a solution?

Comment: THX!. ok to undestand it correctly, the right assumption is $XX=I$? btw why do you left the $I - ...$ out?

Comment: @maximus I haven't made any additional assumptions. Why would you think that I have assumed $XX=I$? The key is, the $Y$ as defined in my answer is idempotent, so it follows that $M=I-Y$ is also idempotent.

Comment: Hey user1551, would you be so kind to explain the last calculation in detail... problem is a little bit, that I do not understand the last line;(

Comment: @maximus The previous line has shown that $Y^2=Y$.

Comment: THX! Now I understand everything!!!

Comment: Sorry for asking again, but would you be so kind to give me a hint for the second example;)

Comment: @maximus Done. See my new edit.

Answer (score -2):

I hope tbis working is correct
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/oJuvw.jpg]

Comment: Welcome to math.se! Please take a look at [how to format mathematics here](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation).